# Geometry/Calculus Question Asking to find volume

Tags: calculus, geometry

> Let $R$ be the region bounded by $y = x^2$, the $x$-axis, the lines $x = 1$ and $x = 5$.
>
> (a) Suppose $S$ is a solid whose base is $R$ and whose cross sections perpendicular to the x-axis are semicircles. What is the volume of the solid, $S$?

I know we have to use integrals to find the region we are looking for, but I'm really unsure how to even set this up. The text mentions something called the Cavalieri's principle but I'm not even sure how to use it.

The answer in the back of the text says it is $\frac{1441}{20}\pi$.

Comment: Have you tried sketching the solid $S$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the volume of the solid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299924/find-the-volume-of-the-solid)